# Default How can I use SRTM/elevation data for vector layer Global Mapper

Tags: global-mapper

I want to create a 3D model of section of a city.
So far the buildings, parcels etc. are digitized, however they do not have any Z/elevation data.
How could I add height value to vectors using SRTM or ASTER or LIDAR anything with some decency in terms of accurate height values?
Is there any way that I could just extract or do some divison or something to get those values for each vector layer in part?

I'm pretty much a GIS and Global Mapper newbie, thus I could use some help.

Answer (score 1):

Using QGIS - Answered [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22601/how-to-combine-information-from-raster-and-vector-layers).

If sum and mean elevation (raster values) will suffice - go for QGIS Zonal Statistics (can be found under Raster - Zonal Statistics - Zonal Statistics in QGIS 2.6)

If you need more stats like majority, maximum, median, minimum, minority, range, standard deviation etc. - go for ArcMap Zonal Statistics (can be found under System Toolboxes - Spatial Analyst Tools - Zonal - Zonal Statistics). Of course you will need ArcGIS with Spatial Extension, to do this.

Well, using Global Mapper I don't know if it is possible. This [link](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/21594) suggests you need to export it to DEM and perform the same operation in ArcGIS.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Well, the thing is I must do it in Global Mapper. Perhaps I'll combine it somehow.