# Creating large amount of random points in binary raster?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, python, r, point-in-polygon

I want to create a point vector dataset of 10000 points (or larger) within a binary raster, where the points should be constrained to areas where the raster value is 1.

I tried the following steps.

1. Polygonize raster
2. QGIS: Vector -> Research Tools -> Random Points

This works fine up to 2000 points but anything above just causes QGIS to crash.

Is there a way to create a vector dataset with a large number of point features constrained by a binary raster (or the polygonized version of it)?

The following tools are at my disposal, ranked from most to least favourable: QGIS, Python, R, ArcGIS

This is what I'm going for, only with 10x the point features.

[image: 1k random points]

Comment: How big is your raster, typically?

Comment: The one in the example above is 19200 x 9600. The typical raster is around 10000 x 10000 pixels.

Comment: Okay, the more RAM your machine has the better. I dare not test on a 10,000x10,000 raster on my little PC here, although you could always divide the raster, sample in parts, and join...

Comment: why polygonize the raster? do you mind this answer is useful for you? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22601/how-to-combine-information-from-raster-and-vector-layers

Comment: Because then I can use the "Random Points in Polygon" function, whereas QGIS doesn't have a "Random Points inside specific values of a Raster" function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a way in R:

Make a test raster, 20x30 cells, make 1/10 of the cells set to 1, plot:

```
> require(raster)
> m = raster(nrow=20, ncol=30)
> m[] = as.numeric(runif(20*30)>.9)
> plot(m)
```

For an existing raster in a file, for example a geoTIFF, you can just do:

```
> m = raster("mydata.tif")
```

Now get a matrix of the xy coordinates of the 1 cells, plot those points, and we see we have cell centres:

```
> ones = xyFromCell(m,1:prod(dim(m)))[getValues(m)==1,]
> head(ones)
       x    y
[1,] -42 85.5
[2,] 102 85.5
[3,] 162 85.5
[4,]  42 76.5
[5,] -54 67.5
[6,]  30 67.5
> points(ones[,1],ones[,2])
```

Step 1. Generate 1000 (xo,yo) pairs that are centred on 0 in a box the size of a single cell. Note use of `res` to get the cell size:

```
> pts = data.frame(xo=runif(1000,-.5,.5)*res(m)[1], yo=runif(1000,-.5,.5)*res(m)[2])
```

Step 2. Work out which cell each of the above points is going into by randomly sampling 1000 values from 1 to the number of 1 cells:

```
> pts$cell = sample(nrow(ones), 1000, replace=TRUE)
```

Finally compute the coordinate by adding the cell centre to the offset. Plot to check:

```
> pts$x = ones[pts$cell,1]+pts$xo
> pts$y = ones[pts$cell,2]+pts$yo
> plot(m)
> points(pts$x, pts$y)
```

Here's 10,000 points (replace the 1000 above with 10000), plotted with `pch="."`:

[image: points in ones]

Pretty much instantaneous for **10,000** points on a **200x300** raster with half the points as ones. Will increase in time linearly with how many ones in the raster, I think.

To save as a shapefile, convert to a `SpatialPoints` object, give it the right coordinate system reference (the same as your raster) and save:

```
> coordinates(pts)=~x+y
> proj4string(pts)=CRS("+init=epsg:4326") # WGS84 lat-long here
> shapefile(pts,"/tmp/pts.shp")
```

That will create a shapefile that includes the cell number and offsets as attributes.

Comment: This is looking very promising. My R has gotten a little rusty: How would I be able to export the points to a vector format (Shapefile, geojson, gml,...whatever really) - I need to save the locations of the sample points for later use.

Comment: Edits show how to read a raster and convert pts to shapefile...

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I work with large datasets, I like to run tools/commands **outside** of QGIS such as from a *standalone script* or from *OSGeo4W Shell*. Not so much because QGIS crashes (even if it says "Not responding", it's probably still processing the data which you can check from the **Task Manager**), but because more CPU resources such as RAM are available to process the data. QGIS itself consumes a fair chunk of memory to run.

Anyway, to run a tool outside QGIS (**you would need to have installed QGIS via the OSGeo4W installer**), follow the **first 2 steps** as described by @gcarrillo in this post: [Problem with import qgis.core when writing a stand-alone PyQGIS script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129959/problem-with-import-qgis-core-when-writing-a-stand-alone-pyqgis-script/130102#130102) (I suggest to download and use his .bat file).

Once the PATHS are set, type `python` into the command line. For convenience, copy the following code into a text editor such as Notepad, edit the parameters such as the pathname of your shapefile etc. and then paste the whole thing into the command line by *Right-click > Paste*:

```
import os, sys
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")

QgsApplication( [], False, home + "/AppData/Local/Temp" )

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C://OSGeo4W64//apps//qgis", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
app = QApplication([])

sys.path.append(home + '/.qgis2/python/plugins')
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
from processing.tools import *

shape = home + "/Desktop/Polygon.shp"
result = home + "/Desktop/Point.shp"
general.runalg("qgis:randompointsinlayerbounds", shape, 10000, 0, result)
```

Using the script, I ran the **Random points in layer bounds** tool for a fairly large shapefile and it took under 20 seconds to generate 10k points. Running it inside QGIS took almost 2 minutes so atleast for me, there's a significant difference.

Comment: Excellent alternative, +1. Just tested this for my application and while it is a bit slower than the R approach it creates the desired results.

Comment: @Kersten - Awesome, glad it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use GRASS GIS directly for this job - **Stratified random sampling: Random sampling from vector map with spatial constraints**:

https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.random.html#stratified-random-sampling:-random-sampling-from-vector-map-with-spatial-constraints

Additionally, random sampling from vector map by attribute and a few other methods are implemented in the command.

Note: The v.random version exposed in QGIS through processing does not reflect the full functionality but just a simplified view.